# In SwiftUI, how do you limit which @Published properties of an ObservableObject trigger a view to be refreshed?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In `SwiftUI`, is there a way to control which `@Published` properties in an `@ObservableObject` trigger a view to be refreshed?

On the iPad and macOS, I find it common to share a `model` between multiple views that are presented on the screen at the same time. This `model` is an `ObservableObject` with numerous properties that are `@Published`. However, a chance to any of those properties appears to cause SwiftUI to rebuild the view hierarchy, even if not entirely necessary.

Consider the example below. There is a `model` called `Order` that has several published properties. There are two views presented side-by-side that both depend on `Order`. If you make a change to `Order.name` or `Order.address` from the `CustomerView`, then that triggers the `CartView` to be refreshed as well, even though it is only dependent on `Order.items`.

Ideally, I want a way to tell `CustomerView` to ignore updates to `Order.items` and to tell `CartView` to ignore updates to `Order.name` and `Order.address`. But since `order` is an `@EnvironmentObject` I can't figure out how to do that.

**Alternative Solution:**

One way I could work around this to not use `@EnvironmentObject` and instead just pass in the `Order` through a standard property initializer. Then declare separate `@Binding` properties on `CustomerView` and `CartView` for managing the state. This works, but quickly becomes a lot of duplication if the views and models have a lot of properties.

*Not like it matters too much, but this is mostly for iPadOS and macOS development.*

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               ContentView                │
│                                          │
│┌──────────────────┐ ┌──────────────────┐ │
││                  │ │                  │ │
││   CustomerView   │ │      CartView    │ │
││                  │ │                  │ │
││                  │ │                  │ │
│└──────────────────┘ └──────────────────┘ │
└──────────────────────────────────────────┘



final class Order: ObservableObject {
  @Published var name: String
  @Published var items: [Item]
  @Published var address: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var order = Order()
  
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      CustomerView()
      CartView()
    }.environmentObject(order)
  }
}

struct CustomerView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
  
  // This view gets rebuilt when 'order.items' is changed.
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Name", text: $order.name)
      TextField("Address", text: $order.address)
    }
  }
}

struct CartView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var order: Order
  
  // This view gets rebuilt when 'order.name' or 'order.address' is changed.
  var body: some View {
    List(order.items, id: \.id) { item in
      ItemView(item)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to refactor your code then, I think. Using `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` basically means that whenever an object notifies of any change (via `objectWillChange`), the view's body should be recomputed. If you don't want that, refactor

Comment: Agreed, but I feel like I'm missing something obvious. `@EnvironmentObject` requires an `@ObservableObject` so if you want to pass around a model using the environment then the model must be observable. In a document-based desktop app, the model could easily have a large number of properties and the window could easily have a large number of views that all need to access the "current document". But you certainly don't want all of the views refreshing when a single property on the document changes.

Comment: You are worrying too much about the view hierarchy, SwiftUI is (should be) smart enough to re-render only the views subscribed to data that changes, regardless how many published properties your observed object has

Comment: This looks like a bug, the view should not update if there are no changes in dependent properties. I recommend to submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: [Cristik] Maybe so, but at least on macOS the behaviour that I'm seeing is such that any `View` with an observed object as a property will be rebuilt if any published property on that object is changed, regardless if that property is used to create the view. In larger desktop applications, this can cause a lot of views to be rebuilt when they don't need to be. This causes a noticeable slowdown when performing user actions like selection and dragging which might be updating the model.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any change in `@ObservedObject` causes the body of the observing view to be recomputed and child views to be *initialized*; though their body aren't necessarily recomputed too.

Comment: @NewDev, the defect is exactly in that `CartView`/s body **is** recomputed on `order.name` changed, even though entire `CartView` does not depend on `name` property. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

Comment: @kennyc, the only workaround I see for now is to separate independent properties into different ObservableObject view model classes and use exactly one per view (one-to-one relationship).

Comment: @Asperi, but that seems to me to be by-design, because of direct dependence on `@EnvironmentObject`, no?

Comment: @Asperi, Yeah, a ViewModel architecture is clearly the recommended way to go. In a large desktop application, it's quite common to have a lot of views on the screen at once and creating a separate ViewModel for each view can feel rather superfluous, especially if those views only depend on reading and writing to a few properties in the model. Thanks for your input.